# How to get CategoryIds and Category name for selected Products in magento2 ?

Tags: magento-2.1, catalog, adminform, massaction

I want to get CategoryIds and CategoryName to salected Produts; but in my code; I can give CategoryIds to All Products

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

```
    $productCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

    $collection = $productCollection->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->load();

    foreach ($collection as $product) {
          echo 'Name = '.$product->getName().'<br>';
        foreach ($product->getCategoryIds() as $category_id) {

            echo 'Category =' . $category_id. '<br>';

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to filter collection by category ids or category names?

Comment: first of all ; I want to to filter collection by category ids

Answer (score 0):

Try this. On your collection

```
$collection->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
        array('finset' => array('7', '8', )),
));
```